# CSS Menu - All menu items show when hover 1 Menu Item

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a `CSS/HTML` based menu and when  i hover on a single menu item All child menu items shown. what can be the

- root course for this problem ?
- where should i start debugging in CSS file or HTML list ?
- What can be the common curses for this ?

**(Rather posting the code i prefer to solve this for own learning experience !**

Comment: You will need to post the code, quite difficult to tell the problem without that.

Comment: It's probably the wrong element. But without any Code this question is as silly as asking mom where the Babies come from....

Comment: For a true learning experience, try to figure it out on your own. 1) Validate your HTML 2) Once you're sure it's valid, create a test case with as little CSS as possible and figure out what the problem is

Comment: Without code it's difficult to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a CSS selector issue.  If more things are showing than you expect, it could be that the CSS selector (for :hover) is too broad and is picking up more items than you intend.  You may need to make the CSS selector be more selective so that it only affects some of the child menus at a given time.  You might be able to do this by defining different selectors that start with different IDs and then apply the :hover to just child elements of a specific element.  If your code is a pure HTML/CSS implementation, that seems to be the most likely cause.  It could also be that they way you have structured the HTML causes all of the child menu items to fall under the same parent element (or branch), so you may also need to ensure that each set of child menus has some unique parent/grandparent that you can base the CSS selectors on.  Hope that helps point you in the right direction--good luck with figuring it out!